# C++ OpenGL trouble trapping cursor in window

Tags: c++

I am using OpenGL and I try to trap my cursor inside my game window (using both        SetCursorPos
and
    ClipCursor)

But, these conflict with my camera rotation code as my camera is rotated with my mouse. If there is a way to do it, please let me know. If possible, I would be willing to make it so that when the cursor reaches an edge of the screen, it jumps to the opposite edge (though I fear that would also conflict with my camera code).

EDIT: My camera code:

```
float heading;              // Also Y rotation, hard to explain
GLfloat yrot;               // Y Rotation
GLfloat lookupdown = 0.0f;
float mouseX, mouseY, oldMouseX, oldMouseY;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        // save old mouse coordinates
        oldMouseX = mouseX;
        oldMouseY = mouseY;

        // get mouse coordinates from Windows
        mouseX = LOWORD(lParam);
        mouseY = HIWORD(lParam);

        // these lines limit the camera's range
        if (lookupdown < -90)
            lookupdown = -90;
        if (lookupdown > 90)
            lookupdown = 90;

        if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) > 0) {     // mouse moved to the right
            heading -= 3.0f;
            yrot = heading;
        }
        else if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) < 0) {     // mouse moved to the left
            heading += 3.0f;
            yrot = heading;
        }

        if ((mouseY - oldMouseY) > 0) {     // mouse moved up
            lookupdown += 3.0f;
        }
        else if ((mouseY - oldMouseY) < 0) {     // mouse moved down
            lookupdown -= 3.0f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set it back to the center of the window every frame.

Comment: What Ben said. And use the delta of the movement, not the absolute position.

Comment: Neither C++ nor OpenGL provide facilities to control the cursor.  You are presumably using some other library to do so, and what library that is will matter to your question.  (From the two functions you mention, I assume that it's the Windows API?)

Comment: @Ben, if I set it back to the center of the window every frame (which I tried already), it prevents my camera from rotating. I don't know why, it just does. I can update the question with my camera code if needed.

Comment: @TrevorPowell I am just using the Windows API to reset the mouse position (as seen in the question when I said I tried SetCursorPos and ClipCursor).

Comment: @Ben I stand corrected. I was using Bandicam to record my framerate, and I realized that it actually brings my framerate down to ~1FPS. It makes it so it takes my camera a long time to respond to input. :/